# Not able to block IP address via AWS WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, web-application-firewall

I have created a Cloudfront distribution and associated a Web ACL rule with it that blocks all IP addresses that doesn't match my IP address condition. But it is not blocking any IP address. What am I doing wrong?.

Comment: Could you please provide details about the rule?

Comment: I have created a Web ACL rule with one rule that contains one condition. The condition has 2 IP addresses. The rule says if a request matches all the rule, allow the IP addresses that is in the condition and block all other IP addresses.

Comment: One more thing I am working with WAF and Cloudfront(no ALB or CloudFormation). And I have used my webserver domain name in Origin Path in CLoudfront Distribution(no S3 bucket)

Comment: Capture the response headers.  Do you see `X-Cache:` and `Via:`, both mentioning CloudFront?

Comment: I've got the same issue and it's driving me nuts.